# Transitive dependency not included in war package

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

A war project is dependent on com.mycompany:somejarname:1.0. It is dependent on slf4j-log4j12 (this is needed only at runtime by that jar).

The packaged war doesn't include slf4j-log4j12- my understanding is that it should be included since because of transitive dependency: war --> somejarname --> slf4j-log4j12. The dependency tree does show the dependency but it is not included in the final war package.

```
[INFO] +- com.mycompany:somejarname:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- common-crypt:common-crypt:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-spring:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
```

Any suggestions? Using Maven 3

**UPDATE**: this works with Maven 2.2.1, but not with Maven 3.0.4. [Dependency resolution](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution) in Maven 3 was changed from 2.2.1.

**UPDATE**: [dependency tree](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution) functionality in Maven 3 is same as in Maven 2.2.1 so the tree above shows slf4j-log4j12.

> Furthermore, not all parts of the Maven 2.x resolution API could be bridged onto Aether. Most notably the maven-dependency-tree shared component which is used for mvn dependency:tree still uses the legacy resolution code. As such, the output from mvn dependency:tree can differ from the actual dependency tree used by Maven itself to derive the classpaths of a project (see MSHARED-167 for an example of such a discrepancy)

Comment: Without the pom file it's hard to guess what's wrong?

Comment: the pom contains lot of components -- I will try to reproduce it on a smaller project and then post the POM

Comment: Have you solved the problem or not? If so please post the solution as answer.

Comment: I have explicitly listed the dependency in my war project (war --> somejarname --> slf4j-log4j12). I couldn't reproduce this issue when I tried with smaller projects.

Answer (score 0):

Found the same issue using Maven 3.2.5 from Eclipse Mars (m2e plugin).

**Solved it by using Maven 3.3.3** (needs Java 7 or 8) that comes packaged by default with Eclipse Mars.