# why is transitive dependency not included my final war?

Tags: tomcat, maven-3, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

Somewhat similar question is posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606285/transitive-dependency-not-included-in-war-package) But no answers there.

I have multi-module maven project

when I run `mvn dependency:tree`,
I see the following

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Service 2.2.22-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building common 2.2.22-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  +- com.mycompany.project:jar:2.1.115:compile
           +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
```

No other configuration to exclude any library is done in pom.xml.
In my final `war/WEB-INF/lib`,

I see `commons-codec-1.6.jar`, `commons-httpclient-3.1.jar`, `httpclient-4.3.2.jar`.
But I do not see `commons-codec-1.2.jar`. why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of including both commons-codec jars, which can lead to conflicts and issues, Maven's **[dependency mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)** selected `commons-codec-1.6.jar`

> - **Dependency mediation** - this determines what version of a dependency
>   will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered.
>   Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition"
>   which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to
>   your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a
>   version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if
>   two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree,
>   until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since
>   Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first
>   declaration wins.
> - "nearest definition" means that the version used
>   will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies,
>   eg. if dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D
>   2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could
>   explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0